Integrate $ \int_{} 1 + \tan x\tan(x+\theta) {\rm{d}}x$ quickly .
Integrate $ \int_{} 1 + \tan x\tan(x+\theta) {\rm{d}}x$

I am expecting better new elegant approaches for this simple integral and let us see how shorter it can be.

My try :
$$I = \int_{} 1 + \tan x\tan(x+\theta) {\rm{d}}x = \int_{} \frac{1-\tan x\tan\theta+\tan^2x+\tan x\tan\theta}{1-\tan x\tan\theta} {\rm{d}}x \\= \int_{} \frac{\sec^2x}{1-\tan x\tan\theta} {\rm{d}}x = \cot\theta \ln\left|\frac{\cos x}{\cos(x+\theta)}\right| + C$$

Rewrite the integrand as $\cos (\theta ) \sec (x) \sec (\theta +x)$

Bit shorter.
$$\int \frac{\tan x - \tan (x+\theta)}{-\tan\theta} dx$$
$$=-\cot \theta \ln\bigg|\frac{\sec x}{\sec(x+\theta)}\bigg|+C$$
What I had done
$$\tan(x-(x+\theta))=-\tan\theta =\frac{\tan x - \tan (x+\theta)}{1+\tan x\tan(x+\theta)}$$

Good, that's what I was trying to do as well.

@MathArt I typed so fast while hiding from my tuition teacher, I should explain what I did in my answer

@Gwen lovely observation mam
